# `dict().values in dict()` fails in Python 3.7 but succeeds in Python 3.11

Tags: python, dictionary

on Python 3.7.13

```
dict().values in dict()
```

gives,

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

on Python 3.11,

```
dict().values in dict()
```

gives,

```
False
```

what is the reason for this change?

Comment: Are you sure you mean `dict().values` and not `dict().values()`? `dict().values` returns a function, which should be unproblematic in all versions, while `dict().values()` returns some sort of view object, which probably has all sorts of funny semantics.

Comment: but for a function, `def f(): pass` `f in dict()` works in both versions of python. `type(dict().values)` gives `builtin_function_or_method`, it works differently than a function here.

Comment: Odd that it says `unhashable type: 'dict'`, as that's not the type.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245165/discussion-on-question-by-apostofes-dict-values-in-dict-fails-in-python-3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of the expression `dict().values` is a "method wrapper"; an object that contains a method *and* the object on which the method is to be called.

If you do, for example,

```
hash(dict().__str__)
```

you get an exception in 3.7, but not in later versions. The difference is in the function [`wrapper_hash`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8136606769661c103c46d142e52ecbbbb88803f6/Objects/descrobject.c#L1315) in CPython which has [changed](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ac20e0f98d6727ba97a9575bfa2a11b2f6247c35) from hashing the wrapped object — hence the `'dict'` in the error message even though we are not (explicitly) hashing a dict — to using its identity instead.